# Extending Vuetify button to show success after save

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I'm trying to extend Vuetify's `v-btn` so that after its `loading` prop goes from `true -> false` I can temporary change the button.

the `watch` function gets called, but it's not swapping out the `slot` for the `Saved!` text.

```
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind="{ ...$attrs, disabled: $attrs.disabled || success }">
    <slot v-if="!success"></slot>
    <template v-else><v-icon>check</v-icon> Saved!</template>
  </v-btn>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue.extend({
    name: "SaveButton",
    data: () => ({
      success: false,
    }),
    watch: {
      loading(loading, wasLoading) {
        if (!loading && wasLoading) {
          this.success = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.success = false;
          }, 300e3);
        }
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a component?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure i got exactly what you were trying to do. However this code works:

```html
<template>
  <v-btn>
    <slot v-if="!success" />
    <template v-else>
      <v-icon>mdi-check</v-icon>Saved
    </template>
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib'

  export default {
    name: 'SaveButton',
    extends: VBtn,
    data: () => ({
      success: false,
    }),
    watch: {
      loading (loading, wasLoading) {
        if (!loading && wasLoading) {
          this.success = true
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.success = false
          }, 300e3)
        }
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

##### Aclarations

1. If you are using a SFC you use the extends prop (You can see it under name) [Vue API documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends)
2. You need to put mdi- before check
3. You need to import the VBtn component if you want to extend it